# Inserting using id in many-to-many relationship in SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, many-to-many, flask-sqlalchemy

Suppose I have an Article model and a Tag model in a many-to-many relationship using an association table. The tag has attributes id (primary key) and tag_name. Articles have many tags.

I want to create a new Article with tags, and I have the ids of existing tags to be added.

I have something like this:

```
self.tags = [ Tag.query.filter_by(id=tag_id).first() for tag_id in tag_ids ]
```

(I am using Flask-SQLAlchemy.)

How do I do this without unnecessarily querying for the Tag objects?

I want to in effect just insert the tag_id, article_id association in the association table; can I do this without using a raw statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have the association table mapped directly, like `TagAssociation`, then you can just create `TagAssociation(article_id=x, tag_id=y)`.   If OTOH the table is only present in the `secondary` argument of `relationship()`, the ORM doesn't have a direct system, you'd need to run an `insert()`, though you'd use `Session.execute()`, that is, `Session.execute(assoc_table.insert(), params={"article_id": x, "tag_id": y})`.

Comment: how about if the article is a new instance?